# Informality, modern messaging, and editing

Tags: discussion, editing

The "acceptable" modes of messaging and exchange of information are constantly evolving. A forum such as this one was unimaginable* just twenty years ago, yet today it can seem positively antiquated when compared to other platforms.

I present as an example today's [**the difference between anyway and anyways also a lot and a lots ?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/24750d83-c43a-4515-87f4-a9d8e935be20/view-source)

I was tempted immediately to edit this question in several ways so that it might conform to... to what? The question as it is would be unexceptional if received in my messaging app!

Will it be wise to accept without revision questions formatted and presented as if in a messaging app? Since many new learners are much more accustomed to these platforms that to our stodgy web-based model, is accommodating them the best way to make them feel at home? Or should we instead expect learners to dispense with the near-dialect of English that constitutes, for many of them, their first experience of the language, and expect instead that they conform to a minimum standard of "proper" usage? How might we accomplish this without alienating them, or presenting ourselves as a bunch of hidebound troglodytes?

A tangent: when editing a question, I often wish it were possible to use the editing itself as a tool with which to promote progress in punctuation, spelling and grammar, but I haven't come up with a way to bring the quærent's attention to an edit in commentary without distracting from the content of the question. Do experienced hands have any tips?

---

*<sub>I except USENET, with which our presentation has something in common, because the majority of "regular folks" never knew of it, and still don't.</sub>

Comment: If you feel that by editing a post you improve its legibility and comprehensiveness, you should go ahead and edit. Not my downvote (i.e. *demurrer*)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I couldn't agree more, but that's not what this question is concerned with.

Comment: PED - I can't figure out _what_ this question is concerned with....

Comment: @J.R. PED...(I like it!) is asking whether we should leave short hand text alone, 'cos that's how kids roll today. And after all, if we are an English language site, we cannot afford to rest on our laurels, or behave  like the fuddy duddies of the past.  So, should we respect current English orthographical trends? Or should we demand that users write in standard English? (Please correct me, if I'm wrong)

Comment: I've [moved the comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46131/discussion-on-question-by-p-e-dant-informality-modern-messaging-and-editing). The thread was mostly about the style and not the substance, and I think the concerns have been noted and the comments detract from the question itself at this point.

Answer (score 7):

I'm expressing my opinion about editing *posts* on ELL. I am aware correcting other people's posts is a thorny issue, but I'll try to explain my approach, and the rationale behind it.

### Edit

Whenever a post contains solecisms that risk receiving a negative response; typos, missing capital letters, ungrammatical phrases, poor formatting, etc. if it offers something to ‘chew on’, it should be edited for clarity.

### Why?

I think everyone will agree it is a strain to read a long wall of text filled with typos. Would anyone object if a user applied common sense and edited the post? Adding paragraphs, fixing typos, replacing CAPS with lower case letters (minuscule), and using correct punctuation marks  not only helps the OP, it also helps readers and non native speakers alike.  As long as the edit does not alter the OP's query, edits should aim to improve legibility. That type of edit should be encouraged, why should a shorter post be treated any differently?

To reiterate, an edit by a community user should, above all, be seen as an act of courtesy towards readers; and secondly, as a gesture of kindness.

### Textese: Why the rush?

Textese fulfills an important communicative function on mobile phones, but ELL is not a cell phone device.

In my very humble opinion, a question written *entirely* in **[textese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/textese)** on an English language site is bordering on rudeness. It shows laziness, slackness, and disrespect. Furthermore, not everyone understands these abbreviations, it definitely alienates the more mature users among us — *ahem*, *cough* — and possibly not every non-native speaker will be familiar with their meanings.

### Weak writing ≠ textese

> guys, i have noticed that in a movie he said anyways and also have lots of time so why he didn't say a lot instead of lots ?

IMHO the above is not textese, the above is neither an example of today's orthographic trends pioneered by the millennial and Z generation; the above was clearly written by a young non native speaker.

Since the OP posted his question, it has been edited and it is more comprehensible.

Comment: Thank you very much for a well thought-out response. it's the kind of input I was hoping to elicit. I've never seen the term _textese_ before, but that only demonstrates my status as a troglodyte, and I'm glad to add it to my lexicon. In regard to that dialect: One of the reasons for my post was the increasing occurrence of questions which obviously were composed on a mobile device. In many developing nations, mobile devices are much more commonly used to access forums like ours than are desktop devices. Whether we like it or not, that is the future.

Comment: @P.E.Dant as I explained in my answer, I don't consider the citation to be pure textspeak, it perhaps shares certain characteristics, (limited use of punctuation)  but it's clear the user is not a native speaker. Moreover, the user is not communicating with one person, who might be familiar with their dialect,  but, possibly, with hundreds of visitors and users. A text message is not the same thing as writing a question about the English language.

Comment: To those who are interested in this issue: "For a technology that only really went ‘live’ in the mid-1990s, it took scholars a while to attend to
texting. Since the early 2000s, however, research from a range of disciplines and a number of
countries has been growing. While much of this work falls beyond the immediate interests of
language scholars, it does reveal the increasing importance and application of texting in both
scholarly and public contexts."  http://nl.ijs.si/janes/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/thurlowpoff11.pdf

Comment: You omitted `I really like when people help me to get the answer thank you a lot ^_^ ` which is firmly in the genre. It's hard to find examples that haven't been edited.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I omitted the "Thank you" line,  because it had nothing to do with the question. ELL is a Q&A website, not a chat forum.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hmm. That practice sounds strangely familiar. ^_^

Comment: Yes, EL&U brainwashed me well :-)

Comment: I think the whole point about textese over and above what has already been said is that, if you are posting a question, you want to get to the widest range of people who can answer. So write in plain English which is understood by all, not some code only known to those who use it. With all due respect to the younger amongst us, the more mature users are less likely to understand textese but more experienced in the language and hence be able to answer.